# How to update WooCommerce order item quantity (existing order)?

Tags: php, mysql, woocommerce, decimal, product-quantity

How can I correctly update/change/modify `order item quantity` of order items in existing **WooCommerce** orders?

(I am not talking about cart items before order creation like in [How to update WooCommerce order item quantity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612308/how-to-update-woocommerce-order-item-quantity) )

I would please like to know both ways:

- via SQL ( `UPDATE` )
- via the WordPress way (`wp functions`)

I know that the `product_qty` field is located in the `wc_order_product_lookup` table.

I know that the `meta_key` field containing the `_qty` value ( where the `meta_value` field is containing the **order item quantity**) is located in the `woocommerce_order_itemmeta` table.

As a side note:

I am using the *WooCommerce Advanced Quantity* plugin ( https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-advanced-quantity/11861326/support ) which enables **decimal/float** quantities (which I use as weight) instead of **integer** ones.

`wc_order_product_lookup` table: `product_qty` field - **integer** quantities (decimals are cut off)

`woocommerce_order_itemmeta` table: `meta_key` = `_qty`, `meta_value` - **decimal** quantities

Thus, both fields (integer & decimal/float) should be correctly updated.

Any clue would be highly appreciated.

---

I found 2 resources pointing in the right direction:

1. [Update and save an order item in the order on Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956457/update-and-save-an-order-item-in-the-order-on-woocommerce-3)

```
$order = wc_get_order($ordernum);
  foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item )
   {
    $item->set_quantity($qnty);
    $item->save();
   }
$order->save();
```

2. https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/order-items.html

`wc_add_order_item_meta( $order_item_id, '_qty', 2, true ); // quantity`

Comment: If the "weighting" is applied evenly, do it as you `SELECT` rather than at `UPDATE` time.

Comment: which code yould you suggest, @Rick James ?